# How to reauthenticate using Firebase's own token

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, jwt, token

Looking online and at the Firebase documentation I could not find a way to reauthenticate a user using the token (JWT) previously returned. I did find [firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(token)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signinwithcustomtoken) but it does not seem to be what I should be using. Is there a way to do that with the Firebase SDK?

```js
const { user } = await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
const token = await user.getIdToken(true) // will be stored for the next session

// ...

// next session after retrieving the persisted token
const { user } = await firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(`Bearer ${token}`) // response status 400
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't think that's what [`signInWithCustomToken`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth) is for. That's for tokens from a custom / third-party authentication system, not for Firebase's own tokens. Firebase can only authenticate with the methods you've configured which from your question appear to be _"email and password"_. Firebase will restore a user session automatically (provided it's still valid)

Comment: That makes sense but I am wondering if there is an equivalent for Firebase's own tokens. I have to be able to do so in order to maintain multiple authenticated users at the same time across several applications and browsers on mobile, using shared tokens saved in cold storage.

Comment: Firebase saves its tokens in local storage already and when you initialise your app, it picks the token back up. It's not particularly clear what you're trying to do

Comment: Absolutely, my issue is that local storage is browser specific. I need to be able to automatically sign someone in using a token that I previously saved on a different browser. I also need to be saving a collection of token (not logged in all at the same time so that the user can switch between their currently logged in account without re-entering their credentials)

Comment: Short answer. You can't sign in a user with a Firebase ID token. Imagine if Firebase auth allowed this out of the box. Any short lived ID token that gets leaked can now be transformed to a long lived session. You need to build your own custom auth solution to do so.

Comment: I question this statement *I need to be able to automatically sign someone in using a token that I previously saved on a different browser*. So you're saying if someone logs in using Safari and then then quits Safari and opens Firefox, it should re-authenticate them automatically in Firefox?